# Insert primary key of unique value into foreign key

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert

If I have a two tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    username TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE games 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    player1 INTEGER REFERENCES users,
    player2 INTEGER REFERENCES users,
    comment TEXT
);
```

How can I insert a new row into the `games` table given two usernames?

The primary keys of the users would need to be looked up by their names in the `users` table first and then inserted into the `games` table. What's the best way to do this?

So, instead of

```
INSERT INTO games (player1, player2) 
VALUES (1, 2);
```

how can I combine this with looking up the id values from usernames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use subqueries to lookup the two usernames based on their `id`s:

```
INSERT INTO games (player1, player2, comment)
SELECT
     (SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = 1),
     (SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = 2),
     'good luck';
```

Comment: I didn't know that `select` statements can be evaluated in place of values. This gave me the clue I needed. But your example is flipped around. What I ended up doing is this. `INSERT INTO games (player1, player2) VALUES ( (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = 'Alice'), (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = 'Bob') );` Are you sure the first `select` in your example shouldn't be `value`?

Comment: @SU3 I'm surprised that your version even works (it would not on many versions of SQL).  Sometimes the `VALUES` clause only allows _values_, as the name implies.  I would probably stick with my version.

Comment: But what do I do if I also need to insert a value? Like if also want to set the `comment` field to `'good luck'` at the same time.